# Rails3 Conditional Statements in Controller Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to write a conditional statement in my tasks controllers for a simple rails3 application.

Users have many tasks and tasks have one user.

When creating a task, we can chose who owns it:

```
<%= collection_select(:task, :user_id, User.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => true}) %>
```

I want the system to send an email to the owner of the task, only when it's created for someone else. I.e. I do not need to receive an email when I create a task for myself.

My mailer's working fine and in my tasks controller, I've tried this:

```
def create
    @task = Task.new(params[:task])    
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save and @task.user_id = current_user.id      
        format.html { redirect_to(tasks_path, :notice => 'Task was successfully created.') }      
        format.xml  { render :xml => @task, :status => :created, :location => @task }        
      elsif @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to(tasks_path, :notice => 'Task was successfully created.') }      
        format.xml  { render :xml => @task, :status => :created, :location => @task }        
        TaskMailer.new_task(@task).deliver      
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @task.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
     end
    end
  end
```

But it's not really working... Any chance of some assistance.

Comment: what error are you getting and where?

Comment: also imho you should move the mailing-stuff to the `Task`-model and use an `after_save`-callback for the mailing stuff.

Comment: maybe the error is due to the use of `and` instead of `&&`?

Comment: @PeterWong `and` and `&&` are totally the same

Comment: @Simon In this case, they are totally the same, but their behaviour is quite different. Check http://avdi.org/devblog/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/ to avoid getting burned by this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `@task.user_id = current_user.id` with `@task.user_id == current_user.id`.

This is not the cause of your error, but you're saving your task two times if `@task.user_id != current_user.id`. You  could do something like this instead:

```
def create
    @task = Task.new(params[:task])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to(tasks_path, :notice => 'Task was successfully created.') }      
        format.xml  { render :xml => @task, :status => :created, :location => @task }        
        TaskMailer.new_task(@task).deliver if @task.user_id != current_user.id  
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @task.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! The above was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Are you not storing the id of the creator? If you do, all the data you need is in the model. Thus just implement an private instance method in Task model. Something like the following

```
# Task model
private

def notify_assignee
  if new_record? || user_id_changed? && creator_id != user_id
    TaskMailer.new_task(@task).deliver
  end
end
```

Call the above method `after_save`

```
# Task model
after_save :notify_assignee
```

In case you are not storing the creator_id in the database, create an attribute accesor called `:creator_id`.

```
# Task model
attr_accessor :creator_id
```

In the controller, before saving, do

```
# Tasks controller
@task.creator_id = current_user.id
```

and the above method would still work.

You controller re directions would automatically be simplified to

```
 if @task.save
    format.html { redirect_to(tasks_path, :notice => 'Task was successfully created.') }      
    format.xml  { render :xml => @task, :status => :created, :location => @task }        
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @task.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
 end
```

And also this would be the right way to go as the "business logic" (which in your case is *send assignee an email notifying that someone else has assigned a task to them*) would reside in the model.

Comment: You'd have to check if the notification has already been sent, else the task assignee would be spammed every time the task is changed.This is not bad in itself, but the OP's business logic doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my code to incorporate the logic to send emails only if the task is being created for the first time or if the assignee has been changed.

Comment: Hi, have tried another solution above but like the idea of moving out into the model. Cheeers

Answer (score 1):

It's because of this line, you're using an assignment `=` instead of the comparision `==`
Also the current_user should be `@current_user` instead because you didn't specify it in the method. (Or you have a method `current_user()` that you did not post. Then it's fine)

```
if @task.save and @task.user_id = current_user.id
```

It should be

```
if @task.save and @task.user_id == @current_user.id
```

also imho you should move the mailing-stuff to the `Task`-model and use an `after_save`-callback.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need change this line: `@task.user_id = current_user.id` to `@task.user_id == current_user.id`